# Suddenly getting "NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerConfiguration.isParameters" in CI build

Tags: maven

I'm suddenly seeing a CI Maven build failing with something like this:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project CheckoutMs: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerConfiguration.isParameters()Z
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.6.1/maven-compiler-plugin-3.6.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-eclipse-compiler/3.3.0-01/groovy-eclipse-compiler-3.3.0-01.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.6/plexus-component-annotations-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/apache/xbean/xbean-reflect/3.7/xbean-reflect-3.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0/google-collections-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-eclipse-batch/2.5.5-01/groovy-eclipse-batch-2.5.5-01.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.2/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.1.7/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.0.4/plexus-utils-2.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.7/aether-util-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/3.1.0/maven-shared-utils-3.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.5/commons-io-2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-incremental/1.1/maven-shared-incremental-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/6.0_ALPHA/asm-6.0_ALPHA.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/2.0-M5/qdox-2.0-M5.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/2.8.1/plexus-compiler-api-2.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/2.8.1/plexus-compiler-manager-2.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/2.8.1/plexus-compiler-javac-2.8.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
```

From some analysis, I can see that the "isParameters" method is available in version 2.8.3 of the plexus-compiler-api, but not in 2.8.1, which is being used here.  This is not a dependency, direct or indirect, of the project being built.

This error is repeatable in the project where it's happening.  It started happening at 2 minutes after midnight starting on 1/26.  The previous build of this, which ran 6 minutes before that, on the previous day, did not see this symptom.

I also looked at the git commit ids of every repository pulled from for this build, and they are identical between the last successful build and this first (and continuing) failure.

This means that something must have changed in the infrastructure.  I don't maintain that.  A different team does.  What I'd like to get from this posting is any clues I can pass on about what might have changed that could have caused this.

Comment: based on that stack trace it looks like your project uses groovy-eclipse compiler ...furthermore the dependency you've mentioned are things which dependencies of the maven-compiler-plugin itself which means if it's a different one than the configuration of the maven-compiler-plugin could have been changed via a parent pom...apart from that I assume you are building with the same JDK version as before?

Comment: We just managed to resolve this, but I don't understand why it only just started failing. We noticed that we were using version 3.6.1 of the maven compiler plugin, but other related builds were using version 3.8.0. This project has been at 3.6.1 for quite a while. I changed it to 3.8.0, and now it all works.

Comment: I imagine this could have happened if somewhere in the 3.6.1 dependency tree, there's a reference to an artifact without a version, which I'm guessing would take the latest, and that artifact just had a new release, which caused this now to break. I can't explain this otherwise.

Comment: The maven-compiler-plugin defines all it's dependencies via fixed version numbers...so very unlikely..But it sounds like that the version for the plugins have not been pinned. Please report is this happens again...Strong recommendation is to define all plugins with it's . version in your build...(usually company pom )...

Comment: It was pinned, at 3.6.1.  It was like that for months.  It then started failing at midnight on that particular day. There wasn't a single source code change between the last successful build and the failed build.  I fixed it by upgrading to 3.8.0. The m-c-p may define all of its dependencies with fixed versions, but how about all of its children?

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by `plexus-compiler-eclipse` not properly resolving its dependency on `plexus-compiler-api`.  Not sure why - here's its [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/codehaus-plexus/plexus-compiler/blob/plexus-compiler-2.8.6/plexus-compilers/plexus-compiler-eclipse/pom.xml).

It's currently resolving the version of that dependency via the Maven Compiler Plugin, **which is why updating it to latest e.g.:**

```
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
```

fixes the dependency, e.g. it will cause:

```
< [INFO]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:jar:2.8.1
< [INFO]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-manager:jar:2.8.1
< [INFO]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-javac:jar:2.8.1
---
> [INFO]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:jar:2.8.4
> [INFO]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-manager:jar:2.8.4
> [INFO]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-javac:jar:2.8.4
```

The API change that causes the issue was introduced in [this commit](https://github.com/codehaus-plexus/plexus-compiler/commit/4ef4382067935958dedadf50945bb2b91712a9c0), first released in the plugin 2.8.2, which is why referencing latest e.g 2.8.6 without triggering the API dependency transitively via `maven-compiler-plugin` latest causes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

FYI openjdk17
NoSucMethodError: 'void org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.eclipse.EclipseJavaCompiler.logCompiling

<plexus.version>2.13.0</plexus.version>
<compiler.version>3.10.1</compiler.version>

Use 2.12.1